# React router v4 render method refactor

Tags: react-router, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a component that works well. But I'd like to change the code, so that 
`React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })` *would be written using* **JSX**.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
    if (loggingIn) return <div></div>;
    return !authenticated ?
    (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
    (<Redirect to="/documents" />);
  }} />
);

Public.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Public;
```

Comment: Do you know what the component is going to be ahead of time? If not, if it changes, then I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: @todd-chaffee yes it changes depending on a path/route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a small change to the parameters of your `Public` component.

```
const Public = ({ component: Component, loggingIn, authenticated, ...rest }) => (
```

It took some experimenting on my part to understand how to capture the component parameter *in order for it to be used as JSX*, so I created a [working example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/tchaffee/pen/mmGEqY), with the code below. (Note I am using `HashRouter` because `BrowserRouter` doesn't work in Codepen. Ignore it - not important to the solution. I also removed some of the logic in your `Public` component to focus on the solution. In your final code you could of course add the `loggingIn` and `authenticated` logic back into your `Public` component).

```
const {
  HashRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link
} = ReactRouterDOM

const Home = () => (
  <span>Home</span>
);

const Another = (props) => (
  <div>
    <span>Another</span>
    <div>Bah: {props.bah}</div>
  </div>
);

const NotHome = (props) => {    
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Not Home</div>
      <div>Logging in: {props.loggingIn}</div>
      <div>Authenticated: {props.authenticated}</div>
      <div>Other prop: {props.otherProp}</div>
      <div>Route props(match.path): {props.match.path}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Public = ({ component: Component, loggingIn, authenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
    // return (React.createElement(Component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated }));
    return (<Component {...props} {...rest} loggingIn={loggingIn} authenticated={authenticated} />);
  }} />
);

ReactDOM.render((
  <HashRouter>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/public">Public</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/another">Another</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <p>The rendered route component:{' '}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Public path="/public" component={NotHome} loggingIn="could be" authenticated="perhaps" otherProp="bar" />
          <Public path="/another" component={Another} loggingIn="no..." authenticated="not" bah="baz" />
        </Switch>
      </p>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

I thought the key to understanding this was to see [how Babel transforms the JSX](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=%3CPublic%20component%3D%7BMyComponent%7D%20%2F%3E%0A) into `createElement` where you'll notice that:

```
<Public component={MyComponent} />
```

Gets transformed to:

```
React.createElement(Public, { component: MyComponent });
```

With the essential part being `{ component: MyComponent }` and thus the required change in your parameters. But wait, this doesn't make much sense. Because your parameter of `{ component }` is the same as `{ component: component }`. See the [MDN docs on destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with the important sections being [Assignment without declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration) and [Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

So the only thing really happening above in my working example is that the variable name is now capitalized... Wat?

Digging a bit deeper, and [using Babel some more](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=console.log(%3Ccomponent%20%2F%3E)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%3CComponent%20%2F%3E)%3B%0A%0A), the real reason is the way JSX treats lower case versus upper case component names. Compare:

```
console.log(<component />);

// Which is transformed to:
console.log(React.createElement("component", null));
```

With:

```
console.log(<Component />);

// Transformed to:
console.log(React.createElement(Component, null));
```

You need to use upper case to get the variable name instead of a string. (Which leads to another solution, but it would mean capitalizing the property name, which is not standard so I'm not providing that solution).

And in fact, the React [JSX In Depth docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type) do briefly mention how upper case is treated (emphasis mine):

"The first part of a JSX tag determines the type of the React element.

Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component. **These tags get compiled into a direct reference to the named variable**, so if you use the JSX `<Foo />` expression, `Foo` must be in scope."

And also in the [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) section:

"When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string `'div'` or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX."

The link above goes on to show some useful examples.

Comment: I refactored the code according to your proposal but *loggingIn is undefined*.  Switched back to previous version everything works (

Comment: My example on Codepen works, and shows the value of `loggingIn`. You're missing something.

Comment: I still can't figure it out what's wrong with my code, because I couldn't fixed an error: 
`Exception from Tracker recompute function:
meteor.js?hash=... ReferenceError: loggingIn is not defined ...` , but anyway thanks for helping, and I'll keep searching for a solution of that issue.